# Azure python vm create fails when trying to create image with custom image

Tags: python, azure, command-line-interface

VM create fails with is osDisk error: 
msrestazure.azure_exceptions.CloudError: Changing property 'osDisk.image.uri' is not allowed.

Code snippet is as follows:

```
 storage_profile=azure.mgmt.compute.models.StorageProfile(
            os_disk=azure.mgmt.compute.models.OSDisk(
                caching=azure.mgmt.compute.models.CachingTypes.none,
                create_option=azure.mgmt.compute.models.DiskCreateOptionTypes.from_image,
                name=OS_DISK_NAME,
                os_type='Linux',
                vhd=azure.mgmt.compute.models.VirtualHardDisk(
                    uri='https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/{1}.vhd'.format(
                        STORAGE_NAME,
                        OS_DISK_NAME,
                    ),
                ),
                image=azure.mgmt.compute.models.VirtualHardDisk(
                    uri='https://xxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/vm-images/Centos67-Azure.vhd'
                ),
            )
```

image is defined in the python API and the URi defined works fine with the Azure CLI

API azure==2.0.0rc3

If it helps this is the transaction being sent to azure:

**url**: hps://management.azure.com/subscriptions/b97ddb69-f825-48b4-9e19-48eb3b4c8267/resourceGroups/dev-eu-vnet9-rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/centos67-api

**header parameters**: {'accept-language': 'en-US', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'x-ms-client-request-id': 'f65196f4-0e3b-11e6-a61b-b499baffc71a'}

**body content**: {'properties': {'storageProfile': {'osDisk': {'osType': 'Linux', 'createOption': 'fromImage', 'name': 'centos67-api', 'caching': 'None', 'vhd': {'uri': 'https://deveuvnet9rg9944.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/centos67-api.vhd'}, 'image': {'uri': 'https://deveuvnet9rg9944.blob.core.windows.net/vm-images/Centos67-Azure.vhd'}}}, 'hardwareProfile': {'vmSize': 'Standard_DS1'}, 'osProfile': {'adminUsername': 'cloud_user', 'computerName': 'centos67-api', 'adminPassword': 'xxxxxxxx'}, 'networkProfile': {'networkInterfaces': [{'id': '/subscriptions/b97ddb69-f825-48b4-9e19-48eb3b4c8267/resourceGroups/dev-eu-vnet9-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/centos67-api'}]}}, 'location': 'eastus'}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./azure_client.py", line 220, in 
    result.wait() # async operation
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msrestazure/azure_operation.py", line 639, in wait
    raise self._exception
msrestazure.azure_exceptions.CloudError: Changing property 'osDisk.image.uri' is not allowed.

Comment: from the class definition for OSDisk:

Comment: According to the document for REST API [Create or update a virtual machine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163591.aspx), the request body content not includes the property `image` of the `osDisk` for the `storageProfile`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved.  Turned out the error returned is somewhat misleading.  The issue was that there was that the target disk already existed and therefore couldn't be modified (i.e. change property error).

Once the target had a unique name the process worked properly and I was able to create VMs from my custom image.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [document](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.mgmt.compute.models.html#azure.mgmt.compute.models.StorageProfile), the class `StorageProfile` construction function has three parameters include `image_reference`, `os_disk` and `data_disk`. The parameter `image` in your code should be the class [`azure.mgmt.compute.models.ImageReference`](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.mgmt.compute.models.html#azure.mgmt.compute.models.ImageReference), not the class `azure.mgmt.compute.models.VirtualHardDisk`.

As reference, here is the sample code from the [document](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resourcemanagementcomputenetwork.html#create-virtual-machine).

```
storage_profile=azure.mgmt.compute.models.StorageProfile(
    os_disk=azure.mgmt.compute.models.OSDisk(
        caching=azure.mgmt.compute.models.CachingTypes.none,
        create_option=azure.mgmt.compute.models.DiskCreateOptionTypes.from_image,
        name=OS_DISK_NAME,
        vhd=azure.mgmt.compute.models.VirtualHardDisk(
            uri='https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/{1}.vhd'.format(
                STORAGE_NAME,
                OS_DISK_NAME,
            ),
        ),
    ),
    image_reference = azure.mgmt.compute.models.ImageReference(
        publisher=IMAGE_PUBLISHER,
        offer=IMAGE_OFFER,
        sku=IMAGE_SKU,
        version=IMAGE_VERSION,
    ),
)
```

Hope it helps.
Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: ImageReference is for using Published images from the Azure Store, not for custom images uploaded Azure.  That works perfectly fine.  Unfortunately I need to use customized images that we create and upload

Comment: This is part of the definition for OSDisk. Look at the definition for image

class OSDisk(Model):
    """
    Describes an Operating System disk.

    ...
       :param image: Gets or sets the Source User Image VirtualHardDisk. This
     VirtualHardDisk will be copied before using it to attach to the Virtual
     Machine.If SourceImage is provided, the destination VirtualHardDisk
     should not exist.
    :type image: :class:`VirtualHardDisk
     <azure.mgmt.compute.models.VirtualHardDisk>`
    ...